# Laravel eloquent search both table in one to many relationship table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

My two table `Member` and `Deposit` there has  **one to many** relationship one member has multiple deposit in `Deposit` table i want to search by multiple column both table which will have to match.

**This is my `Member` Table**

```
1.id,
2.branch_id,
3.village_id,
4.user_id,
5.name,
6.phone,
7.email,
8........
```

**My `Deposit` Table**

```
1.meber_id,
2.user_id
3.deposit_date,
4.deposit_amount,
5.total_amount,
6..........
```

**My Controller Code**

```
$depo = Deposit::with(['member'=>function($query){$query->where('branch_id',$request->branch_id)->where('status','running')->get();}])->where('user_id',$request->user_id)->whereDate('deposit-date','>=',$from_date)->whereDate('deposit-date','<=',$to_date)->get();
```

if i do that then ....`$query->where('branch_id',$request->branch_id)->get().....` section is not working please help me any one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$depo = Deposit::whereHas('member', function($query) use ($request){
         $query->where([
                        ['branch_id' => $request->branch_id], 
                        ['status'=> 'running']
                       ])
                  })
         ->where('user_id',$request->user_id)
         ->whereDate([
                      ['deposit-date','>=',$from_date],
                      ['deposit-date','<=',$to_date]
                     ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguous, but looks like you need to `use` the `$request` in the `with` function.

```
$deposits = Deposit::with(['member' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('branch_id', $request->branch_id)
        ->where('status', 'running')->get();
}])->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
    ->whereDate('deposit-date', '>=', $from_date)
    ->whereDate('deposit-date', '<=', $to_date)
    ->get();
```

But the `with` method wont filter down your query it will simply limit the number of members returned with all the deposits.  It's not searching in the member table.

UPDATE 04/12/2018

Without checking the docs at all, and completely off the top of my head.

```
Deposit::with('member', function($query) use($request){
    $query->where('branch_id', $request->branch_id)
        ->orWhere('village_id', $request->village_id)
})->where(function($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('user_id', $request->user_id)
        ->whereDate('deposit-date', '>=', $from_date)
        ->whereDate('deposit-date', '<=', $to_date)
})->orWhereHas('member', function($query) use($request){
    $query->where('branch_id', $request->branch_id)
        ->orWhere('village_id', $request->village_id)
})->get();
```

Comment: `@John Halsey` please give me suggestion how can i search both table `**Member ad Deposit**`

Comment: which columns do you want to search?

Comment: `@John Halsey` Member Table `branch_id, village_id` and Deposit Table `user_id , deposit-date` column

Comment: `@John Halsey` please give me suggestion